# Connecting two ATA HDDs at same port

Tags: hard-drive, bios, ata

Here is an machine with only one ATA port ( rest is some of SATA ). So I need to connect my two ATA hard drives at same port. I've tried to connect them as master and slave, but they don't work in this way. I just see some of weird name at HDD field in BIOS, or even see nothing. Sometimes there an 8 GB HDD, when I've got 80 GB and 40 GB hard drives. To have access to HDD I need to plug only one of them. Does anyone had same problems? Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that your drives are "incompatible" in the meaning that the do not cooperate well on the same ATA-port/bus.

Try every possible alternative that you have a option (jumper) setting for on each drive (Master, Slave, Cable sel).
If you're lucky, one option of all possible will work. It is possible that there will be no working option.

Comment: I've tried every possible combination of master-slave connections. As well turned on "PATA only" under "Compatible" IDE mode in BIOS. That "PATA only" supposed to help, but for me - don't work. The problem is that they just invisible in BIOS ( when both connected ) so I can't even configure them somehow.

Comment: `tried every possible combination` - Then you have nothing left but to replace at least one of the drives.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my mistake. I was constantly throwing jumper away. I thought it was useless piece of plastic. Now everything all right.